# How to make the word of the day in android using sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a dictionary app and I wanted to make one feature that is the word of the day. I have no idea about the date and time functions in android. Can someone help me? It needs to display each word from the database everyday randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Selecting a Random Row from an SQLite Table](http://www.bernzilla.com/2008/05/13/selecting-a-random-row-from-an-sqlite-table)

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Autoincrement `_id` for each word you add to database, and then randomize `id`

```
Random r = new Random();
int id = r.nextInt(numWords)-1;
```

and then:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE _id = " + id;
```

You can add last word id to another storage (database) to keep your words from repeating.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT
```

Above statement can help to fetch a random word from your table.